# '@error: Solution Not Found' for estimating system of equations

Tags: python, optimization, non-linear-regression, gekko

I'm trying to estimate parameters of a system of equations. I get an error return which is`Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found`.
Is it due to too few degree of freedoms? There seems no other information to deal with the error`No solution`.

Model and script are attached below:

**System of Equations:**

```html
\[y_{jh} = \beta_{j0} + \sum_{k=1}^{K}\beta_{jk}x_{hk} + \epsilon_{jh}\]
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostmath.com/Math/MathJax.js?config=OK"></script>
```

where  ß<sub>jk</sub> and ß<sub>j0</sub> are parameters  that are unkown and need to be estimated.

**Objective function** (Minimize Residuals):

```html
\[\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{h=1}^{H}\epsilon_{jh}\]
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostmath.com/Math/MathJax.js?config=OK"></script>
```

**Constraints:**

Some of rows in data contain missing value, so I add constraint on them. They are subject to:

```html
\[\begin{align}
\frac{y_{jh}}{y_{j_{1}h}} &= \frac{\beta_{j0} + \sum_{k=1}^{K}\beta_{jk}x_{hk} + \epsilon_{jh}}{\beta_{j_{1}0} + \sum_{k=1}^{K}\beta_{j_{1}k}x_{hk} + \epsilon_{j_{1}h}}
\end{align}\]
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostmath.com/Math/MathJax.js?config=OK"></script>
```

where  y<sub>j<sub>1</sub>h</sub> ​is the first non-missing point in  y<sub>jh</sub>​, and  y<sub>jh</sub>​ is non-missing points in row h.

Python Codes:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

model = GEKKO(remote=True)

# =============================== simulated data =============================

h_size = 500  # sample size
k_xvar = 5  # number of X (variables)
j_cate = 5  # number of y (number of equations)

np.random.seed(1234)

data_X = np.random.normal(0, 10, size=(h_size, k_xvar+1))
data_X[:, 0] = 1  # intercept term

beta = [np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=k_xvar+1) for _ in range(j_cate)]
data_y = np.array([
    data_X@beta[j] +
    np.random.normal(100, 10, size=h_size) for j in range(j_cate)
])
# randomly select 10% of observations and replace one value of each of them with np.nan
data_y[
    np.random.choice(data_y.shape[0], int(h_size/10), replace=True),
    np.random.choice(data_y.shape[1], int(h_size/10), replace=False)
] = np.nan

# get index of rows and cols where data is nan and non-nan
index_nan = np.where(np.isnan(data_y))
index_notnan = np.where(~np.isnan(data_y))

# ============================= gekko object =============================

beta_jk = model.Array(model.FV, (j_cate, k_xvar+1))
for j in range(j_cate):
    for k in range(k_xvar+1):
        beta_jk[j, k].value = 0
        beta_jk[j, k].STATUS = 1

error_jh = model.Array(model.FV, (j_cate, h_size))
for j in range(j_cate):
    for h in range(h_size):
        error_jh[j, h].value = 0
        error_jh[j, h].STATUS = 1
for j, h in zip(index_nan[0], index_nan[1]):  # where data is nan
    error_jh[j, h].status = 0

ym = model.Array(model.Param, (j_cate, h_size))
for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1]):
    ym[j, h].value = data_y[j, h]

# equations
for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1]):
    model.Equation(
        ym[j, h] == model.sum(
            beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :]
        ) + error_jh[j, h]
    )

# constraints: the ratio y_j/y_1
if len(index_nan[1]) != 0:  # if there exists nan value
    for h in np.unique(index_nan[1]):
        j_notnan = np.where(~np.isnan(data_y[:, h]))[0].tolist()
        for j in j_notnan[1:]:
            model.Equation(
                (ym[j, h]/ym[j_notnan[0], h]) == (
                    (model.sum(beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :])+error_jh[j, h])/(
                        model.sum(beta_jk[j_notnan[0], :]*data_X[h, :]) +
                        error_jh[j_notnan[0], h]
                    )
                )
            )

model.Minimize(
    model.sum(
        [(error_jh[j, h])**2 for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1])]
    )
)

# Application options
model.options.SOLVER = 1

model.solve(disp=True)
```

And the returns is:

```py
 apm 222.29.98.194_gk_model5 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            1
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :         7481
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :         2451
   Equations    :         5051
   Residuals    :         5051

 Number of state variables:           4931
 Number of total equations: -         5051
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :           -120

 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------

Iter    Objective  Convergence
......

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    42.2448999999906      sec
 Objective      :    55181039.5947782
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------

 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2185, in solve
    raise Exception(response)
Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found
```

How do I check where the error originates from and get successful solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `APOPT` solver fails to find a solution. Switching to `IPOPT` with `m.options.SOLVER=3` produces an error:

```
This is Ipopt version 3.12.10, running with linear solver ma57.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:    26601
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:     4994

Exception of type: TOO_FEW_DOF in file "IpIpoptApplication.cpp" at line 891:
Exception message: status != TOO_FEW_DEGREES_OF_FREEDOM evaluated false:
  Too few degrees of freedom (rethrown)!

EXIT: Problem has too few degrees of freedom.
 
 An error occured.
 The error code is          -10
```

Switching to BPOPT (`m.options.SOLVER=2`) shows that there is a potential divide-by-zero issue that evaluates as `NaN`. Try rearranging the equation (`a/b==1` to `a==b` to avoid this problem or adding constraints to make the denominator >0 or <0.

```py
model.Equation( (ym[j, h]/ym[j_notnan[0], h]) == (
   (model.sum(beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :])+error_jh[j, h])/(
      model.sum(beta_jk[j_notnan[0], :]*data_X[h, :]) +
        error_jh[j_notnan[0], h]
   ))
```

Rearranging the equation as:

```py
model.Equation(
  (ym[j, h] * (model.sum(beta_jk[j_notnan[0], :]*data_X[h, :]) +
     error_jh[j_notnan[0], h]) == (ym[j_notnan[0], h]) * 
     (model.sum(beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :])+error_jh[j, h])))
```

gives a successful solution.

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            1
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :         7481
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :         2451
   Equations    :         5051
   Residuals    :         5051
 
 Number of state variables:           4931
 Number of total equations: -         5051
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :           -120
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with BPOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
 BPOPT Solver v1.0.6
-----------------------------------------------------
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  2.92792E+05  2.97344E+05
    1  1.93773E+04  2.39292E+05
    2  2.34740E+05  6.55490E-08
    3  2.38837E+05  1.55937E-09
    4  2.39278E+05  9.07134E-10
Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  BPOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    86.3358000000007      sec
 Objective      :    239292.116505756     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the full code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

model = GEKKO(remote=True)

# =============================== simulated data =============================

h_size = 500  # sample size
k_xvar = 5  # number of X (variables)
j_cate = 5  # number of y (number of equations)

np.random.seed(1234)

data_X = np.random.normal(0, 10, size=(h_size, k_xvar+1))
data_X[:, 0] = 1  # intercept term

beta = [np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=k_xvar+1) for _ in range(j_cate)]
data_y = np.array([
    data_X@beta[j] +
    np.random.normal(100, 10, size=h_size) for j in range(j_cate)
])
# randomly select 10% of observations and replace one value of each of them with np.nan
data_y[
    np.random.choice(data_y.shape[0], int(h_size/10), replace=True),
    np.random.choice(data_y.shape[1], int(h_size/10), replace=False)
] = np.nan

# get index of rows and cols where data is nan and non-nan
index_nan = np.where(np.isnan(data_y))
index_notnan = np.where(~np.isnan(data_y))

# ============================= gekko object =============================

beta_jk = model.Array(model.FV, (j_cate, k_xvar+1))
for j in range(j_cate):
    for k in range(k_xvar+1):
        beta_jk[j, k].value = 0
        beta_jk[j, k].STATUS = 1

error_jh = model.Array(model.FV, (j_cate, h_size))
for j in range(j_cate):
    for h in range(h_size):
        error_jh[j, h].value = 0
        error_jh[j, h].STATUS = 1
for j, h in zip(index_nan[0], index_nan[1]):  # where data is nan
    error_jh[j, h].status = 0

ym = model.Array(model.Param, (j_cate, h_size))
for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1]):
    ym[j, h].value = data_y[j, h]

# equations
for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1]):
    model.Equation(
        ym[j, h] == model.sum(
            beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :]
        ) + error_jh[j, h]
    )

# constraints: the ratio y_j/y_1
if len(index_nan[1]) != 0:  # if there exists nan value
    for h in np.unique(index_nan[1]):
        j_notnan = np.where(~np.isnan(data_y[:, h]))[0].tolist()
        for j in j_notnan[1:]:
            model.Equation(
                (ym[j, h] * (model.sum(beta_jk[j_notnan[0], :]*data_X[h, :]) +
                        error_jh[j_notnan[0], h]
                    ) == (
                    ym[j_notnan[0], h]) * 
                    (model.sum(beta_jk[j, :]*data_X[h, :])+error_jh[j, h])
                )
            )

model.Minimize(
    model.sum(
        [(error_jh[j, h])**2 for j, h in zip(index_notnan[0], index_notnan[1])]
    )
)

# Application options
model.options.SOLVER = 2 # BPOPT solver

model.solve(disp=True)
```